# Using Logic in XML

Tags: xml

I basically want the following logic in my XML

obj must be ((MASTER || PART) && (Drawing))

This does not seem to work

```
<adapt type="com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCComponent">
       <or>
          <test property="type"
               value="MASTER">
          </test>
          <test property="type"
               value="UGPART">
          </test>
       </or>
       <and>
          <test property="DRAWING"
                value= "">
          </test>
       </and>       
  </adapt>
```

It has to be one of the following (MASTER or PART) and be DRAWING
I am mainly worried about how to add that logic to the XML above

Comment: What does "This does not seem to work" mean?  If you provide more context you're likely to get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your XML elements and attributes have the obvious meanings, I'd expect that the right way to capture the meaning of `((MASTER || PART) && (Drawing))` would be

```
<adapt type="com.teamcenter.rac.kernel.TCComponent">
  <and>
    <or>
      <test property="type"
            value="MASTER">
      </test>
      <test property="type"
            value="UGPART">
      </test>
    </or>
    <test property="DRAWING"
          value= "">
    </test>
  </and>       
</adapt>
```

But this is sheer speculation, since I don't know what software is failing to understand what you are trying to say.